# Slashes stripped from URL

Tags: php, background, return

I've made a small function which checks if a user has an avatar. If so, the avatar is set as a background URL for a div. However, when checking the console on the frontend, slashes are missing from the URL, thus not displaying the background image.

```
function small_avatar($user_ID){
$avatar = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'avatar_user', true);

if(!empty($avatar)){

    return "<div class='setAvatar clan_avatar' style='background: url('".$avatar."');'></div>";

    }
}
```

The use of " and ' is probably breaking something but.. I can't figure it out. Tried to set the style='background' as a variable, and tried to return that as well. No luck.

Comment: the syntax seems ok. Are you sure `$avatar` has the string with shlashes?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh..

All I needed to do was remove the " from the url()

So this works:

```
function small_avatar($user_ID){
$avatar = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'avatar_user', true);

if(!empty($avatar)){

return "<div class='setAvatar clan_avatar' style='background: url(".$avatar.");'></div>";

}
}
```